# Weak and delegate fail-warnings when trying to update tableview through delegate method

Tags: swift, delegates

I been struggling to update my tableview through another class I made.
I then found this stackoverflow solution:
[How to access and refresh a UITableView from another class in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37492211/how-to-access-and-refresh-a-uitableview-from-another-class-in-swift)

But when I follow it step by step and implement all the codes, I get the following errors:

My line:

```
weak var delegate: UpdateDelegate?
```

Gets the warning

```
'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'UpdateDelegate'
```

And my line:

```
self.delegate.didUpdate(self)
```

Gets warning:

```
Instance member 'delegate' cannot be used on type 'APIgetter'
```

Could this be because the code is old and I'm using swift 4? else I cannot see why this should be failing. I hope you can help me :)

**Update:**

My Protocol:

```
protocol UpdateDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didUpdate(sender: APIgetter)
}
```

Snippet from my ViewController containing the tableview:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UpdateDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        APIgetter.addDataFromSQL()
        let updates = APIgetter()
        updates.delegate = self
    }

    //update func
    func didUpdate(sender: APIgetter) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

My APIgetter class in APIgetter.swift:

```
class APIgetter {
weak var delegate: UpdateDelegate?

class func addDataFromSQL (){

//Code to fetch data from API

//Code that comes after DispatchQueue.global & DispatchQueue.main and my result being executed
//result
self.delegate.didUpdate(self)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just update your protocol definition.

```
protocol UpdateDelegate: class {
   // protocol body
}
```

or

```
protocol UpdateDelegate: AnyObject {
   // protocol body
}
```

This is needed (as of Swift 4 I think) because classes are reference types and you can only use a weak reference on reference types. Not value types like structs.

**UPDATE**: You cannot access a property/instance member from a static function the way that you currently are. Remove the class keyword from the function and it should work.

If you want/need to use a single instance of this class throughout your application you can use a static property to make it a Singleton

```
class APIgetter {
    static let shared: APIgetter = APIgetter()
}
```

Then you would be able to access it like this:

```
APIgetter.shared.addDataFromSQL()
```

You could also update the delegate in the same way before calling your function.

```
APIgetter.shared.delegate = self
```

I think in this case though I would use a Singleton without the delegate. Just use a completion handler in your function. Setting and changing the delegate on a shared instance could have some side effects if not managed carefully.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! But I'm still getting the "Instance member 'delegate' cannot be used on type 'APIgetter'" error

Comment: can you post some more code, its difficult to help without knowing how you defined your classes/protocols. What is APIgetter?

Comment: @dafo for that error see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40735415/5175709). Basically the delegate is an **instance** variable. However your `addDataFromSQL` has nothing to do with instances because you defined it to be a **class** function. If you remove the `class` from the `func` then it should work...

Comment: ah yeah, like honey said. the function you are accessing is a static/class function and can't access instance members like that. Thanks Honey